# iPad Air heats up and burns through battery after IOS update

Tags: ios, ipad, battery

When all the apps failed, I was forced to update IOS to the latest two weeks ago.  All seemed fine until streaming Morning Joe burns through 80%+ of the battery and the device becomes hot.  Last month I could watch many hours on 80%

Is there a method (setting) to monitor clock speed and temperature?

Is there a setting to slow the clock speed?

Comment: What do you mean by the apps ‘failed’? They wouldn't open? An error message? Updating apps? What version of iOS did you have? What version of iOS have you updated to now?

Comment: Make an encrypted backup your iPad to iTunes if you haven't already done so, then do an Erase and Restore to zap the iPad back to factory iOS 11. Then restore the backup. Encrypting the backup ensures that all account login information and other stuff is restored. If you don't you'll have to re-enter all login credentials. I have an iPad Air that did not suffer from any problems other than the 23 apps that had not been updated and I needed to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's diagnostics would capture some logs but you'd need Apple to tell you which apps are stuck or chewing through the battery / CPU / energy.

I would focus on checking your last backup and erase things selectively.

If you want to erase slowly:

- reset all settings and then power cycle - that's quick but usually doesn't fix this
- erase all content and settings - then connect to power and do light web apps Safari - don't sign into iCloud, don't restore the backup, don't install any (or many) apps.

Run with the stock OS that was causing the problem without your data or apps to convince yourself that it was your programs and data. If you still see the power drain, then restore the device from iTunes or Apple Configurator or have a technician do it.

TLDR:

1. If it's hardware - none of these will fix it.
2. If you had a corrupt iOS - the restore from USB will fix it
3. If you had programs crashing and data continually trying to update (software bugs or such) - the erase all content and settings will fix it.
4. If a trivial setting got stuck and you needed a minor fix - the reset settings will fix it.
5. The last thing it could be is simply a process that takes a long time to finish. Photos face recognition or upgrading from an old iCloud storage format to a new one can take three or more days to sync if you have 100 GB of photos with many people in them and your photos database has a lot of things to process. It might not even be something you need to fix and can connect to power and WiFi wait this out.